# Edit word doc using webDAV

Tags: webdav

I am using webDAV and able to open the word file from server side. When I make some changes and save it, it is unable to save it on server and instead asking to save it on local. When I select to save it to web address it hits the webdavservlet but still it does not save it and ask to save locally.

Is there anything I am missing, is there any head or param that needs to be set. Or we need to call put method in webdav servlet, if yes how that can be made from ms-word when saved?

Thanks

Comment: I have same problem. Had you solve it?

Comment: I found out the solution check out this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61248151/5018383